# Can I monitor an ATmega406 using an Arduino Uno via SMBus?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, atmega, battery-charging

I would like to build a small Battery Management System (BMS) using an ATmega406 and then maybe use an Arduino Uno to show information about the cells on a computer or a small LCD.

Here's a white paper about it: [Battery Management System Atmega406 summary](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc4083_mega406.pdf)

Anyone knows a good site where I can read about the SMBus and what tools I need on a windows computer to use it?

Comment: SMBus is a subset of I2C.

Comment: That would suggest that the answer is yes

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your best bet would be to use Atmel Studio 6.

And here you can find details about the Atmega406 itself

http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2548-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-Battery-Management-ATmega406_Datasheet-Summary.pdf

Comment: I gonna try out Atmel Studio 6 now. What hardware do I need to connect my computer with the atmega406 ? Can I use something as cheap as this: http://www.amazon.de/Programmer-herunterladen-Netzteil-Atmel-ATMega/dp/B0093DLN74/ref=sr_1_4?s=ce-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1367764371&sr=1-4&keywords=usb+isp+atmel ? And yeah: I am totally new to microcontroller programming. I only worked with an arudino uno for two weeks or so